# Mouse causes lag when dragging windows around

Tags: drivers, 22.04, mouse

recently I have the problem when dragging windows around my screens (I have HP a Elitebook 840 G5 with docking station and 2 additional monitors) that everything starts to lag. Especially when trying to drag around Chrome. Sometimes even Chrome reports a problem and needs to force quit.

First I thought my system is somehow corrupted but without using the docking station (with the notebook mousepad) everything worked fine.
So I docked it in again into the docking station and still with the notebook touchpad everything runs smoothly but as soon as I use my USB-Connected mouse (Roccat Kone Aimo) it starts to lag again. It does not make a difference where I connect the USB from the mouse, I tried the laptop directly and also via the docking station. I tried a wireless mouse with USB receiver and also that one worked fine.
So I think there might be something wrong with the mouse driver on ubuntu (since the mouse works fine on windows (dual boot on laptop).

Does anyone have an idea what I could to about this. I run Ubuntu 22.04 and it should be completely up-to-date. I experienced this issue just a few weeks ago.

Thanks!

Comment: I had similar issue - but the problem was the frequency of the monitor - under 40Hz - I change the cable usb-c to hdmi - with high speed transfer and works great. Your problem could me more different because of using the docking  - which I didn't use.

Comment: Hi @RobertMihaiIonas
I guess I have a different problem. Also without the docking station only using the laptop screen I experience this lag with the Kone Aimo but not with any other mouse or touchpad.